# How do ISPs impose data caps?

Tags: network, monitoring, isp

Nearly in every country, ISP's implement Data caps. Can somebody tell me how do they implement them at software / hardware level ?

1. How do they filter millions/billions of request and decide their speed
   ?
2. What algorithm do they use?
3. Has there been any bypass/exploitation in the past

Comment: 1. and 2. are off-topic since they have nothing to do with information security (i.e. which information need to be protected here?). 3. is off-topic too for the same reason and because we don't help with bypassing restrictions if you even miss a basic understanding of the problem. But a hint: the ISP needs to deliver the packets to you anyway so they can simply add up the packet sizes too while doing this and compare them against the data cap. It's nothing complicated.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Sir if it is off topic can you please ask a mod to move it to appropriate forum as deemed necessary.I wasn't interesetd in bypassing a whole I was just curious that how big-players handle biilions of request/sec .Ain't comparing against packet size ever time a request is made quite inefficient?(whenver i go above quota..they notify me almost immediately).I was only interested in exploitation to understand the pros/cons of its workings(sooner or later isp detects the data hogs ain't it)

Comment: I cannot move it but you might ask at http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/. But, adding the size of the packet and comparing the sum against some limit is really cheap compared to all the other things which need to be done to handle the traffic.

Comment: I agree with steffen. Not being rude, but the answer is very simple. They way they handle billios of request is with strong hardware. But they do the same thing over and over; look at who's using it, and add up the sizes.

Comment: I agree with others that this is simple. Even home routers often have QoS which is same thing. Probably ISP routers have QoS in hardware and they are just vastly more powerful, that's how it is done. And I agree it isn't about security.

Comment: @Xasel look up the term "netflow" - that's the technology you're looking for.

Comment: I am going to delete this questions here and repost it on network.SEx if any mod doesn't move it soon,well I know there maybe some hardware/software algoritthm.I am only interested in whatevr it maybe ,how it works what are it methodologies /algorihtms etc.Thank you guys for your valuable pointers